Problem with seaborn kdeplot() when plotting two figures side by side
I am trying two plot two 2d distributions together with their marginal distributions on the top and side of the figure like so:

Now I wantto combine the above figure with the following figure, such that they appear side by side:

However, when doing so, the marginal distributions arent plotted.. Can anyone help?

The code for plotting the above figure is given here:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import ot
import ot.plot

# Define the mean and covariance for two different multivariate normal distributions
mean1 = [0, 0]
cov1 = [[1, 0.5], [0.5, 1]]

mean2 = [3, 3]
cov2 = [[1, -0.5], [-0.5, 1]]

n = 100

# Generate random samples from the distributions
np.random.seed(0)
samples1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1, cov1, size=n)
samples2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean2, cov2, size=n)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([samples1, samples2]), columns=['X', 'Y'])
df1['Distribution'] = 'Target'
df1['Distribution'].iloc[n:] = 'Source'

# Create a custom palette with blue and red
custom_palette = {'Target': 'blue', 'Source': 'red'}

# Plotting side by side
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 4))

# Jointplot using seaborn
g = sns.kdeplot(data=df1, x="X", y="Y", hue="Distribution", kind="kde", space=0, fill=True, palette=custom_palette, ax=axs[0])
axs[0].set_xlim(-4, 6.5)
axs[0].set_ylim(-4, 6.5)
# axs[0].set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
sns.move_legend(axs[0], "lower right")

# Optimal Transport matching between the samples
a, b = np.ones((n,)) / n, np.ones((n,)) / n  # uniform distribution on samples
M = ot.dist(samples2, samples1, metric='euclidean')
G0 = ot.emd(a, b, M)
ot.plot.plot2D_samples_mat(samples2, samples1, G0, c=[.5, .5, 1])
axs[1].plot(samples2[:, 0], samples2[:, 1], '+r', markersize=10, label='Source samples')  # Increased marker size
axs[1].plot(samples1[:, 0], samples1[:, 1], 'xb', markersize=10, label='Target samples')  # Increased marker size
axs[1].legend(loc=4)

# Common labels and limits
for ax in axs:
    ax.set(xlabel='X')
    ax.set_xlim([-4, 6.5])
    ax.set_ylim([-4, 6.5])

# Remove y-axis from the second figure
axs[1].set(ylabel='')
axs[1].yaxis.set_visible(False)

# Adjust layout and save plot as PDF
fig.tight_layout()

# Show plot
plt.show()


You can't do this directly as the marginal distributions require a jointplot, which is a figure-level plot and cannot directly add extra axes.
It's however fairly easy to modify the JointGrid code to add more axes.
The key is to change:
# add more space to accommodate an extra plot
# gs = plt.GridSpec(ratio + 1, ratio + 1)
gs = plt.GridSpec(ratio + 1, ratio + 1 + ratio)

# change how the space is defined (example for the ax_joint)
# ax_joint = f.add_subplot(gs[1:, :-1])   # use all width but last
ax_joint = f.add_subplot(gs[1:, :ratio])  # use first "ratio" slots

Which gives us:
ratio = 5
space = .2

f = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
gs = plt.GridSpec(ratio + 1, ratio + 1 + ratio)
ax_joint = f.add_subplot(gs[1:, :ratio])
ax_marg_x = f.add_subplot(gs[0, :ratio], sharex=ax_joint)
ax_marg_y = f.add_subplot(gs[1:, ratio], sharey=ax_joint)
ax_ot = f.add_subplot(gs[1:, ratio+1:], sharey=ax_joint)

# Turn off tick visibility for the measure axis on the marginal plots
plt.setp(ax_marg_x.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_y.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_x.get_xticklabels(minor=True), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_y.get_yticklabels(minor=True), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_x.yaxis.get_majorticklines(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_x.yaxis.get_minorticklines(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_y.xaxis.get_majorticklines(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_y.xaxis.get_minorticklines(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_x.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_y.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_x.get_yticklabels(minor=True), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_y.get_xticklabels(minor=True), visible=False)
ax_marg_x.yaxis.grid(False)
ax_marg_y.xaxis.grid(False)

utils = sns.axisgrid.utils
utils.despine(ax=ax_marg_x, left=True)
utils.despine(ax=ax_marg_y, bottom=True)
for axes in [ax_marg_x, ax_marg_y]:
    for axis in [axes.xaxis, axes.yaxis]:
        axis.label.set_visible(False)
f.tight_layout()
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=space, wspace=space)

sns.kdeplot(data=df1, x='X', y='Y', hue='Distribution', fill=True, palette=custom_palette, ax=ax_joint)
sns.move_legend(ax_joint, 'lower right')
sns.kdeplot(data=df1, x='X', hue='Distribution', fill=True, palette=custom_palette, legend=False,
            ax=ax_marg_x)
sns.kdeplot(data=df1, y='Y', hue='Distribution', fill=True, palette=custom_palette, legend=False,
            ax=ax_marg_y)

# Optimal Transport matching between the samples
a, b = np.ones((n,)) / n, np.ones((n,)) / n  # uniform distribution on samples
M = ot.dist(samples2, samples1, metric='euclidean')
G0 = ot.emd(a, b, M)
ot.plot.plot2D_samples_mat(samples2, samples1, G0, c=[.5, .5, 1])
ax_ot.plot(samples2[:, 0], samples2[:, 1], '+r', markersize=10, label='Source samples')  # Increased marker size
ax_ot.plot(samples1[:, 0], samples1[:, 1], 'xb', markersize=10, label='Target samples')  # Increased marker size
ax_ot.legend(loc=4)

Output:

modifying JointGrid for full flexibility
Another approach would be to create a subclass of JointGrid that can accept an existing Figure/GridSpec/Axes as input and use those instead of creating their own.
In the example below, the JointGridCustom class would expect custom_gs=None (default) or custom_gs=(f, gs, ax_joint, ax_marg_x, ax_marg_y) to reuse existing objects. This will allow customization while letting seaborn handle the jointplot:
f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
gs = plt.GridSpec(8, 8)
ax_joint = f.add_subplot(gs[1:6, :3])
ax_marg_x = f.add_subplot(gs[0, :3], sharex=ax_joint)
ax_marg_y = f.add_subplot(gs[1:6, 3], sharey=ax_joint)
ax_ot = f.add_subplot(gs[1:6, 5:], sharey=ax_joint)
ax_bottom = f.add_subplot(gs[7:, :], sharey=ax_joint)

g = JointGridCustom(data=df1, x='X', y='Y', hue='Distribution', space=0, palette=custom_palette,
                    custom_gs=(f, gs, ax_joint, ax_marg_x, ax_marg_y)
                   )
g.plot(sns.kdeplot, sns.kdeplot, fill=True)

Example output:

Full code:
import matplotlib
from inspect import signature

from seaborn._base import VectorPlotter, variable_type, categorical_order
from seaborn._core.data import handle_data_source
from seaborn._compat import share_axis, get_legend_handles
from seaborn import utils
from seaborn.utils import (
    adjust_legend_subtitles,
    set_hls_values,
    _check_argument,
    _draw_figure,
    _disable_autolayout
)
from seaborn.palettes import color_palette, blend_palette

class JointGridCustom(sns.JointGrid):
    """Grid for drawing a bivariate plot with marginal univariate plots.

    Many plots can be drawn by using the figure-level interface :func:`jointplot`.
    Use this class directly when you need more flexibility.

    """
    
    def __init__(
        self, data=None, *,
        x=None, y=None, hue=None,
        height=6, ratio=5, space=.2,
        palette=None, hue_order=None, hue_norm=None,
        dropna=False, xlim=None, ylim=None, marginal_ticks=False,
        custom_gs=None,
    ):

        # Set up the subplot grid
        if custom_gs:
            f, gs, ax_joint, ax_marg_x, ax_marg_y = custom_gs
            assert isinstance(f, matplotlib.figure.Figure)
            assert isinstance(gs, matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec)
            assert isinstance(ax_joint, matplotlib.axes.Axes)
            assert isinstance(ax_marg_x, matplotlib.axes.Axes)
            assert isinstance(ax_marg_y, matplotlib.axes.Axes)
        else:
            f = plt.figure(figsize=(height, height))
            gs = plt.GridSpec(ratio + 1, ratio + 1)

            ax_joint = f.add_subplot(gs[1:, :-1])
            ax_marg_x = f.add_subplot(gs[0, :-1], sharex=ax_joint)
            ax_marg_y = f.add_subplot(gs[1:, -1], sharey=ax_joint)

        self._figure = f
        self.ax_joint = ax_joint
        self.ax_marg_x = ax_marg_x
        self.ax_marg_y = ax_marg_y

        # Turn off tick visibility for the measure axis on the marginal plots
        plt.setp(ax_marg_x.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
        plt.setp(ax_marg_y.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
        plt.setp(ax_marg_x.get_xticklabels(minor=True), visible=False)
        plt.setp(ax_marg_y.get_yticklabels(minor=True), visible=False)

        # Turn off the ticks on the density axis for the marginal plots
        if not marginal_ticks:
            plt.setp(ax_marg_x.yaxis.get_majorticklines(), visible=False)
            plt.setp(ax_marg_x.yaxis.get_minorticklines(), visible=False)
            plt.setp(ax_marg_y.xaxis.get_majorticklines(), visible=False)
            plt.setp(ax_marg_y.xaxis.get_minorticklines(), visible=False)
            plt.setp(ax_marg_x.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
            plt.setp(ax_marg_y.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
            plt.setp(ax_marg_x.get_yticklabels(minor=True), visible=False)
            plt.setp(ax_marg_y.get_xticklabels(minor=True), visible=False)
            ax_marg_x.yaxis.grid(False)
            ax_marg_y.xaxis.grid(False)

        # Process the input variables
        p = VectorPlotter(data=data, variables=dict(x=x, y=y, hue=hue))
        plot_data = p.plot_data.loc[:, p.plot_data.notna().any()]

        # Possibly drop NA
        if dropna:
            plot_data = plot_data.dropna()

        def get_var(var):
            vector = plot_data.get(var, None)
            if vector is not None:
                vector = vector.rename(p.variables.get(var, None))
            return vector

        self.x = get_var("x")
        self.y = get_var("y")
        self.hue = get_var("hue")

        for axis in "xy":
            name = p.variables.get(axis, None)
            if name is not None:
                getattr(ax_joint, f"set_{axis}label")(name)

        if xlim is not None:
            ax_joint.set_xlim(xlim)
        if ylim is not None:
            ax_joint.set_ylim(ylim)

        # Store the semantic mapping parameters for axes-level functions
        self._hue_params = dict(palette=palette, hue_order=hue_order, hue_norm=hue_norm)

        # Make the grid look nice
        utils.despine(f)
        if not marginal_ticks:
            utils.despine(ax=ax_marg_x, left=True)
            utils.despine(ax=ax_marg_y, bottom=True)
        for axes in [ax_marg_x, ax_marg_y]:
            for axis in [axes.xaxis, axes.yaxis]:
                axis.label.set_visible(False)
        f.tight_layout()
        f.subplots_adjust(hspace=space, wspace=space)


    
f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
gs = plt.GridSpec(8, 8)
ax_joint = f.add_subplot(gs[1:6, :3])
ax_marg_x = f.add_subplot(gs[0, :3], sharex=ax_joint)
ax_marg_y = f.add_subplot(gs[1:6, 3], sharey=ax_joint)
ax_ot = f.add_subplot(gs[1:6, 5:], sharey=ax_joint)
ax_bottom = f.add_subplot(gs[7:, :], sharey=ax_joint)

g = JointGridCustom(data=df1, x='X', y='Y', hue='Distribution', space=0, palette=custom_palette,
                    custom_gs=(f, gs, ax_joint, ax_marg_x, ax_marg_y)
                   )
g.plot(sns.kdeplot, sns.kdeplot, fill=True)


Ahh okay, I see - thank you very much!

@Lyft you're welcome. I added another approach to modify the existing JointGrid to take custom objects

To handle these requirements, I previously developed the Python library patchworklib  to freely arrange complex seaborn plots.
Please run pip install patchworklib and execute the following code.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import patchworklib as pw 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import ot
import ot.plot
pw.overwrite_axisgrid() 

# Define the mean and covariance for two different multivariate normal distributions
mean1 = [0, 0]
cov1 = [[1, 0.5], [0.5, 1]]

mean2 = [3, 3]
cov2 = [[1, -0.5], [-0.5, 1]]

n = 100

# Generate random samples from the distributions
np.random.seed(0)
samples1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1, cov1, size=n)
samples2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean2, cov2, size=n)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([samples1, samples2]), columns=['X', 'Y'])
df1['Distribution'] = 'Target'
df1['Distribution'].iloc[n:] = 'Source'

# Create a custom palette with blue and red
custom_palette = {'Target': 'blue', 'Source': 'red'}

# Plotting side by side
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 4))

# Jointplot using seaborn
g = sns.jointplot(data=df1, x="X", y="Y", hue="Distribution", kind="kde", space=0, fill=True, palette=custom_palette, xlim=(-4, 6.5), ylim=(-4, 6.5))
g = pw.load_seaborngrid(g)

# Optimal Transport matching between the samples
ax1 = pw.Brick(figsize=(4,4)) 
a, b = np.ones((n,)) / n, np.ones((n,)) / n  # uniform distribution on samples
M = ot.dist(samples2, samples1, metric='euclidean')
G0 = ot.emd(a, b, M)
ot.plot.plot2D_samples_mat(samples2, samples1, G0, c=[.5, .5, 1])
ax1.plot(samples2[:, 0], samples2[:, 1], '+r', markersize=10, label='Source samples')  # Increased marker size
ax1.plot(samples1[:, 0], samples1[:, 1], 'xb', markersize=10, label='Target samples')  # Increased marker size

(g|ax1).savefig("example.png")

Finally, "example.png" will be generated as below.

